# Custom ItemSource in XAML Not bindable

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I created a custom control which should have an ItemSource.
So I added a BindableProperty and tried to bind it, but I always receive the following error:

*"Position 18:46. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ItemsSource', or mismatching type between value and property.    "*

The Binding: `<controls:SeatsView x:Name="Control" ItemSource="{Binding Rows}">`

Property:

```
public IEnumerable ItemSource
{
    get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
}
public BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SeatsView), defaultValue: null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnItemSourceChanged);
```

If I bind it in code behing like `Control.ItemsSource = v.Rows;` it works fine...

I also tried to add a typeconverter but it doesn't work either

Any ideas

Comment: There is an Spelling error with ItemsSource and ItemSource so that can be an issue.

Comment: Hi, About usage of [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) , you can refer to this document . And Uraitz's answer you can have a try .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindable property should be **static** and **readonly**

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SeatsView), defaultValue: null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnItemSourceChanged);
```